# C#: Getting a collection of child elements values in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm pretty new to XML and C# itself, so I'm sorry if this seems silly. I am trying to get a list of values of a child xml element's value. Let me explain further.

I have xml code like this, for readability I've only included one post, but they're all the same.

```
<posts>
    <post id="1949239" reblogged-from-name="iwanttofly">
    </post>
</posts>
```

Here is the code

```
var rebloggers = (from n in document.Descendants("post") select n.Element("reblogged-from-name")).ToList().Select(x => x.Value);
```

I am greeted with this exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Jimese.Common.Utilities.TumblrUtilities.<>c.<FetchMediaForPage>b__0_1(XElement x) in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Jimese\Utilities.cs:line 20
```

Line 20 is the code above, the `var rebloggers...`

Answer (score 2):

`reblogged-from-name` is not an element, it's an attribute. You should use `n.Attribute("reblogged-from-name")` instead.

```
document.Descendants("post")
        .Select(n => n.Attribute("reblogged-from-name").Value)
        .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as xml to C# deserialization.

Create your classes like:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName="post")]
    public class Post {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="reblogged-from-name")]
        public string Rebloggedfromname { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="posts")]
    public class Posts {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="post")]
        public Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

And then use xml deserialization

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Posts));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(testData)) // test data is your xml
    {
        var result = (Posts) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

Comment: I would discourage this, personally - unless you need it for other reasons. XML querying and manipulation is pretty straightforward in C# without serialization, certainly with LINQ to XML. While this will work, it will take a lot more code than just using `XDocument` etc.